# Move row entries to a third file based on comparison among Files or workbooks one and two

Tags: vba, excel

I think that my question was not clear earlier. So, I am attaching sample data along with a detailed insight into the requirement. Please advice.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUuNFkJdgpStfLH1oBTAvxEgW9V1v13Z5aJ9goA8C0M/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B9LObbHmu0G9pBHbFqbcR4fNJuSr8BvpqJHfVi9J2fg/edit?usp=sharing

Requirement:
a)Compare the data in Files named John.xlsx with Jack.xlsx
b)Specifically compare the Columns B and C .
c)If both Columns match,  then move the entire ROW from Jack.xlsx to a third file Lilian.xlsx which will be having the same columns headers and is just a blank file at the moment.
d)Delete the moved row from Jack.xlsx
e)Save Jack.xlsx and Lilian .xlsx

Does that make any sense?

Thanks for the effort :)

PS: ( sorry, but I am not able to attach more than 2 links in the post coz of my reputation point in the forum is quite low. New to the forum -.-' ). Otherwise, I will put a link for the Lilian.xlsx file as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code and take a look at this site FAQ. [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using native Excel features, rather than trying to code something in visual basic.  For example, try `=MATCH()` formula combined with the autofilter feature, and set the criteria to hide anything that does not match, i.e. comes up "#N/A".

Once you get the data to display as you expect, then copy and paste to new tab, and save-as new.csv.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 sheets. Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3, the code below checks columns C for sheet1 and sheet2 for the first 10 rows. If it finds a match it will copy the data to the first column in sheet3:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
Dim intCurrentRow As Integer

intCurrentRow = 1
For i = 1 To 10
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) Then
        Sheet3.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
        intCurrentRow = intCurrentRow + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Data in sheet 1:

[image]

Data in sheet2:

[image]

Result, Data in sheet 3:

[image]